# How to get the values that have been updated?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

For example: to get the values to create a Trigger that have been passed with INSERT command the following can be done:

```
SELECT @pid=Product_ID, @q=Item_Quantity, @invid=Invoice_ID FROM Inserted
```

So, I would have access to the values that have been passed with INSERT command and use them in SQL Server in my Trigger. 
What would be the equivalent for UPDATE commands?
How would I get the values that I will pass from my program to SQL Server through UPDATE commands?
Something like below gives me an error:

```
SELECT @pid=Product_ID, @q=Item_Quantity, @invid=Invoice_ID FROM Updated
```

Comment: If you have triggers and you are trying in any way shape or form to set any values to a scalar variable, you need to redesign. triggers in SQl server operate on groups of records not one at a time. You need to re-write any existing triggers right now as you nmay be creating a data integrity mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the combination of Inserted and Deleted to know what is updated.  For each row that is updated, the original values will appear in Deleted and the new values will be in Inserted.

So, if you just want to get the new values from your UPDATE, you could use the same query as the one used for INSERT.

Comment: Partially true, except the orginal code is fatally flawed already.

Comment: @nummer31, make sure you test with an update that updates multiple records.

Comment: @nummer31 - you're welcome.  Please look at @HLGEMs comment.  It's very important.  You're query assumes only one row is updated.